# How to programmatically open another app in kiosk mode?

Tags: java, android, kiosk-mode

I want to create an app,that's use to only allow access specific apps in a device.So I tried to pinned the device.Now I want to open another application that is in my specific apps list.
I can't open another app while pinned.
This is the code I used to pinned

startLockTask();

and this is the code to I tried to open another appilication in kiosk mode

```
ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(KioskActivity.this, MyAdmin.class);
                if (myDevicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName()))
                {
                    myDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{getPackageName(), "com.example.pan.pocmdmhelper"});

                    try
                    {



                        PackageManager pm = KioskActivity.this.getPackageManager();
                        Intent it = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.pan.pocmdmhelper");
                        it.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        if (null != it) {
                            KioskActivity.this.startActivity(it);
   Toast.makeText(KioskActivity.this, "Started activity for this package", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(KioskActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        finish();
                    }


                }
```

At the moment I tried to open single app by using it's package name.It's open if I unpinned only

Comment: Have you got the solution?